# google_artifact_registry_repository seems to ignore the 'depends_on' attribute?

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to create a new project and then a new Google Artifact Registry within the new project.  Here are the Terraform resources:

```
resource "google_project" "my_project" {
  name = "My Project Name"
  project_id = "my-project-id-abc"
  billing_account = "BILLING-ACCOUNT-ID"
}

resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "my_ar" {
  provider = google-beta
  format = "DOCKER"
  repository_id = "myreponame"
  location = "europe-west1"
  project = google_project.my_project.project_id
  depends_on = [google_project_service.artifactregistry_googleapis_com]
}

resource "google_project_service" "artifactregistry_googleapis_com" {
  project = google_project.my_project.project_id
  service = "artifactregistry.googleapis.com"
}
```

This almost always fails on first the `terraform apply` with the following error message:

```
Error: Error creating Repository: googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'artifactregistry.repositories.create' denied on resource '//artifactregistry.googleapis.com/projects/my-project-id-abc/locations/europe-west1' (or it may not exist).
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "domain": "artifactregistry.googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "permission": "artifactregistry.repositories.create",
      "resource": "projects/my-project-id-abc/locations/europe-west1"
    },
    "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
]
```

Running the same command immediately again always succeeds with the following message:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_artifact_registry_repository.my_ar will be created
  + resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "my_ar" {
      + create_time   = (known after apply)
      + format        = "DOCKER"
      + id            = (known after apply)
      + location      = "europe-west1"
      + name          = (known after apply)
      + project       = "my-project-id-abc"
      + repository_id = "myreponame"
      + update_time   = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
google_artifact_registry_repository.my_ar: Creating...
google_artifact_registry_repository.my_ar: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_artifact_registry_repository.my_ar: Creation complete after 12s [id=projects/my-project-id-abc/locations/europe-west1/repositories/myreponame]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

It the role of the `depends_on = [google_project_service.artifactregistry_googleapis_com]` attribute not support to wait for everything to be ready before creating the artifact repository?

Comment: I haven't faced this issue but this [list of support channels](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform#terraform_support_for) for Terraform with GCP might be useful

Comment: I'm getting the same problem - did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

More elegant alternative to `null_resource` for resources that need time to provision is [time_sleep](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep.html) resource:

```
resource "google_project" "my_project" {...}

resource "time_sleep" "wait-for-my_project" {
  create_duration = "30s"
  depends_on = [google_project.my_project]
}

resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "my_ar" {
  ...
  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait-for-my_project]
}

# ...etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `null_resource` resource to delay things provided a temporary fix:

```
resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "my_ar" {
  project = google_project.my_project.project_id
  provider = google-beta
  format = "DOCKER"
  repository_id = "myreponame"
  location = "europe-west1"
  depends_on = [null_resource.delay]
}

# in many scenarios the above artifact registries are created while the apis are not yet active
# this is a know issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/9902
# and this delay buys some time before creating the above repositories.
resource "null_resource" "delay" {
  depends_on = [ google_project_service.artifactregistry_googleapis_com ]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 120"
  }
  triggers = {
    project = google_project. my_project.id
  }
}
```